# Servlet getSubmittedFileName removes slashes from path

Tags: servlets, httprequest, content-disposition

I use an `input` element of type `file` to upload a file via an html form.

If the file is uploaded on Internet Explorer, the path is included in the file name.

Getting the file name as follows:

```
Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
for (Part part: parts) {
  if (part.getName().equals(inputName)) {
    System.out.println(part.getSubmittedFileName());
  }
}
```

Leads to the file's file name (in this case the full path because it was uploaded via ie) being displayed without slashes (eg: if the path were `c://directory/file_name` then it's printed as `c:directoryfile_name`)

If I get the header myself with `part.getHeader("Content-Disposition")` then I see that the slashes are present.

What is happening? How can I fix it so that the slashes are in `getSubmittedFileName()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with Internet Explorer:

- https://jira.openolat.org/browse/OO-2154
- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59115

Moreover, internet explorer's default settings for local (intranet) sites sends the entire path while the default behavior for internet sites is to not show the entire path. Therefore this is only an issue for local (intranet) uses, which for me is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on theuy's [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50001441/1529709), this misbehavior on Internet Explorer's part turns out to be *worsened by Tomcat versions newer than 8.0.33*, when it's (trying to) conform to [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) in `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart`. Below is the relevant part of Tomcat's code that removes the backslashes from the filename submitted by Internet Explorer:

```
/*
 * Adapted from FileUploadBase.getFileName()
 */
@Override
public String getSubmittedFileName() {
    (...)
                    // RFC 6266. This is either a token or a quoted-string
                    if (fileName.indexOf('\\') > -1) {
                        // This is a quoted-string
                        fileName = HttpParser.unquote(fileName.trim());
                    } else {
                        // This is a token
                        fileName = fileName.trim();
                    }
    (...)
    return fileName;
}
```

So to keep that from happening, you need to evaluate `part.getHeader("Content-Disposition")` yourself. First, extract the `filename` field from that header, for example like this:

- `filename = header.replaceFirst("(?i)^.*filename=\"?([^\"]+)[\";]?.*$", "$1"));`

Then you need to trim that to the filename, removing the other path elements. Many options here:

- Use regex again: `filename = filename.replaceFirst("^.+\\\\([^\\\\]+)$", "$1");`
- Use the referenced [Apache Commons Fileupload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/)'s  `FileUploadBase.getFileName(...)`
- Use [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)'s `FilenameUtils.getName(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer by default sends the full path when uploading files. You can disable the full path settings:

Internet Options > Security > Internet / Local intranet > Custom Level > Look for "Include local directory path when uploading files to server” and set it to “disable".